# Android Studio Emulator not showing "Always on Top" toggle Button. How to set it always on top?

Tags: android-emulator

In the Android Studio Emulator, in the settings tab, it is not showing "Always on Top" toggle Button. 
How can I set the emulator on always top of the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Go to Android Emulator Settings Window... 
Enable `Show Window Frame Around Device`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Go to options in the android emulator and click: `Settings -> Show window frame around device`. Then the frame will appear around the emulator. Right click on frame around the emulator. Then click on `Always on top`.